# Java Already opened windows inside the Content pane of Main window goes beneath the main window when a menu item is clicked on the main window

Tags: java, click, menubar, childwindow, mainwindow

I am a beginner in java swing an this is my first question. Before asking this I have searched long and not found any solution.

I have a main window with JmenuBar and MenuItems. My problem is that when I click on a menu item the already opened window is going beneath the main Window and new window popup on the top of the main widow.

My requirements

1. When I click on a menu item the opened new window should be on the top of the previously opened window and and both windows should be over the main window.
2. When I click again on menu at this position the drop down menu items should be over all the windows.

I have tried  setAlwaysOnTop(true); to all the menu item windows. but it fails to meet my requirement (2.)

Please help me

Here is my code for main window

```java
public class Main extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Main() {
        setTitle("Menu");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 500, 400, 425);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        JMenu mnPurchase = new JMenu("Purchase");
        menuBar.add(mnPurchase);
        
        JMenuItem mntmAddPurchaseInvoice = new JMenuItem("Purchase Invoice");
        mntmAddPurchaseInvoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Purchase frame = new Purchase();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                
                }
            });
        mnPurchase.add(mntmAddPurchaseInvoice);
        
        JMenu mnSales = new JMenu("Sales");
        menuBar.add(mnSales);
        
        JMenuItem mntmProcessSale = new JMenuItem("Generate Sales Invoice");
        mntmProcessSale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Sale frame = new Sale();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        mnSales.add(mntmProcessSale);
    }
    
    public class Purchase extends JFrame {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Purchase frame = new Purchase();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Purchase() {
        setTitle("Purchase");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 500, 300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        }
    }   
    
    public class Sale extends JFrame {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Sale frame = new Sale();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public Sale() {
        setTitle("Sale");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 500, 300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you reduce this down to a compilable exampe? It sounds like all you need is a JFrame, JMenu, and two windows that you open. As of now it is a bit overkill, with classes that we cannot use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: dear matt, I have edited the code as you said. Now there is a main window with menu bar and menu items. And two child windows viz purchase & sale open from the menu items. Now the first child window goes beneath the main window when clicked either on menu or content pane of main window. I want both the child windows over the main window, and at this stage when clicked on the menu, the drop menu should stay over the child windows. Please help me

Comment: Have you considered a [JDesktopPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html) I suspected it would be possible to make the windows stay above the main jframe, but interleaving that with the menu sounds difficult. What was wrong with using always on top?

Comment: Thanks a lot matt, it works!!! Excellent, meets all my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty trivial fix: Use a JDialog instead of a JFrame for your 'child' frames.

```
public class Sale extends JDialog {
    public Sale(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner);
        setTitle("Sale");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(500, 500, 300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
}
```

I did that for both, Sale and Purchase and it seemed to work as described. I also had to change the action listener code.

```
mntmProcessSale.addActionListener( e -> {
            Sale frame = new Sale(this);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
```

I switched from an anonymous class to a lambda for the syntax of using `this` instead of the alternative `Main.this` notation.

Comment: But matt, minimize and maximize buttons are not there in the child windows, Only Close button is present.Can we fix it too? at least for minimize button?

Comment: Thats funny, you're the second person asking for that recently. Why not just use the close button?

Comment: Ok it is not good to add other buttons to JDialog. Satisfied with Close Button.

Comment: @RenojJoseph adding buttons is ok, but adding window decoration buttons is really tricky. They rely more heavily on native components, and I don't know of a solution that would be cross platform. You might be able to achieve what you want with JFrame and a a focus listeners, but I think you're getting to a point where the effort is going to exceed the reward.

Comment: Yes you are right. Close button is enough at that position.Wasting time to add other window decoration button is worthless especially when it is heavy. I am very happy and fully satisfied with your help and thank you again.